# How can I use data binding through XML to change tabs' text configured with TabLayoutMediator?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-databinding, android-tablayout

I have two tabs in my ViewPager2 which I'd like to configure. Initially, it has a default empty text. After receiving an API response from the remote server, I'd like to change the tabs' text to the data received.

My fragment which contains the ViewPager2 and TabLayout is as follows.

```
class UserDetailsFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragUserDetailsBinding
    private val args: UserDetailsFragmentArgs by navArgs()
    private val viewmodel by viewModels<UserDetailsViewModel> {
        UserDetailsViewModelFactory(
            requireActivity().application,
            args.username
        )
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragUserDetailsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.viewmodel = viewmodel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setupViewPager()
        observeUserDetails()
    }

    private fun setupViewPager() {
        val viewPagerAdapter =
            UserFollowPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager, viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle)
        binding.fragDetailsPager.adapter = viewPagerAdapter
        binding.fragDetailsPager.offscreenPageLimit = 1
        TabLayoutMediator(binding.fragDetailsTabLayout, binding.fragDetailsPager) { tab, position ->
            when (position) {
                0 -> "-"
                1 -> "-"
            }
        }.attach()
    }

    private fun observeUserDetails() {
        viewmodel.userDetails.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            binding.fragDetailsTabLayout.getTabAt(0)?.text = it.followers.toString()
            binding.fragDetailsTabLayout.getTabAt(1)?.text = it.following.toString()
        })
    }
```

As you can see, I am observing `userDetails` from my ViewModel. It's a data class that contains these two fields: followers and following (both are integers). My ViewModel only has that `userDetails` LiveData and an init block to fetch the remote data.

```
class UserDetailsViewModel(application: Application, private val username: String) :
    AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private var _userDetails = MutableLiveData<UserDetails>()
    val userDetails: LiveData<UserDetails>
        get() = _userDetails
    
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                _userDetails.value = userRepository.getUserDetails(username).toDomainModel()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My XML file for the fragment is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.mobile.githubuser.viewmodel.UserDetailsViewModel" />
    </data>
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="?android:colorBackground">

                
                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frag_details_tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_5"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/frag_details_details" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/frag_details_tab_layout_underline"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:alpha="0.3"
                    android:background="?attr/colorNeutral"
                    android:translationY="-1dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/frag_details_tab_layout" />

                <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                    android:id="@+id/frag_details_pager"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/frag_details_tab_layout" />

                
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Is there a way to observe the `userDetails` through XML and change my tabs' text that is set through TabLayoutMediator, thus avoiding the need to use `viewmodel.userDetails.observe(...)` in my Fragment code? If there is, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

use `TabItem` inside `TabLayout` instead of Menu inflating

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/frag_details_tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_5"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/frag_details_details" >

         <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabFollowers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewmodel.userDetails.followers}"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabFollowing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewmodel.userDetails.following}"
             />

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Comment: But using ViewPager2, I must configure the text somehow through TabLayoutMediator (refer to this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayoutMediator))

Comment: This also doesn't compile.